# Load php.ini in each folder

Tags: php, apache

I have a question for the php.ini in root folder, how it can be loaded when reading the page and overwrite the original value.

When I was using the webhosting service, I could simply put the php.ini into root folder, then file will overwrite the existing php.ini value on the original php.ini.

However, I am now trying to use local server for development. I use OSX Server App to setup a server, upgraded php5.4 to 5.5 and check everything is good. The phpinfo function shows nothing wrong. But when I put another php.ini in each folder of developing website, they are not be loaded when page is loading. (Its working if I change the value on original php.ini).

May I ask what I am missing and what should I looking for??

Thank you very much for your help!!

Best regards,

Comment: It is a server configuration problem. [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) may be a better place for this question.

Comment: you may use ini_set for changes...

Comment: @user1844933 I know how to use ini_set....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a development environment you can overwrite php.ini settings using the .htaccess and the vhost configuration of Apache.

If you have "AllowOverride All" set, try adding the following to the .htaccess.

```
php_value  upload_max_filesize  10M
```

Further information see: http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php